# Add nodes with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, nodes

I was trying to add nodes inside `axis` environment but nothing came out. I actually tried several ways... Any help is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95, >=latex']
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5, xticklabels={,,}]
\draw [blue, fill] (-0.5,-3) circle (2pt) node [right] {$b_2$};
\addplot[blue,very thin] table{a.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't plot anything the default axis limits won't change. Also you need `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` to benefit from the coordinate system handling.

Answer (score 2):

Few issues here. First your domain is incorrect. You are drawing the circle at `-0.5,-3` which is outside the view. Hence specify the `max` and `min` values for `x` and `y`. Further, for `pgfplots` versions up to 1.11, you have to specify the coordinates for drawing by `axis cs:` like `(axis cs: -0.5,-3)` to get the position correct.  If you want it outside the box, move `\draw` outside the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.95, >=latex']
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1.5,xmax=3,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
\draw [blue, fill] (-0.5,-3) circle (2pt) node [right] {$b_2$};
\addplot[blue,very thin] {rnd};
\end{axis}
\draw [blue, fill] (-0.5,-1) circle (2pt) node [right] {$b_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Harish! A follow-up question: what if I want to put b_2 below the x-axis?

Comment: @Pittance Use `axis x line=middle` like `ymax=4,axis x line=middle`. Same for y axis if you want on left like `axis y line=left` or `middle`.

Comment: I tried but it only changed the position of the x-axis but couldn't reveal the text ``b_2''.  Perhaps I missed something...

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't clear. I need to put b_2 below the x-axis without changing the x-axis. That is, I want b_2 below the original box.

Comment: @Pittance See the edit.