# Chemfig picture as node in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, chemfig, chemistry

I'm not an expert using LaTeX. I know how to draw the curve in `pgfplots`, but I don't have any idea on how to add the Newman projections inside the graph as a node in order to obtain something like what you can see in the picture:

[image: energy levels of various conformations]

Comment: Of course I also know how to draw the Newman Projection with chemfig ;-) But ho w to combine them with the plot?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242219/add-nodes-with-pgfplots can get you started? If not, then could you provide an example document that shows both the graph and the chemfig drawings, to use as a starting point for potential answerers?

Comment: And welcome to the site, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably useful as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=newman}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, ymin = -20, ymax = 20]
    \addplot[mark=none]{x^3};
    \node[above] at (1,-15){\tiny\newman[scale=0.75]{\hspace*{3.5mm}\ch{CH3},\ch{H},\ch{H},\hspace*{3.5mm}\ch{CH3},\ch{H},\ch{H}}};
    \node[above] at (-1,5){\tiny\newman[scale=0.75](75){\hspace*{3.5mm}\ch{CH3},\ch{H},\ch{H},\ch{CH3},\ch{H},\ch{H}}};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```